# PHP syntax. Boolean operators, ternary operator and JavaScript

Tags: php, syntax

In JavaScript I have  a habit of using the following fallback evaluation

```
var width = parseInt(e.style.width) || e.offsetWidth() || 480
```

meaning `width` will get the last non-zero (non-null...) value
However, in php I can't write

```
$a = $_GET['id'] || 1;
```

I have to write so

```
$a = $_GET['id']?$_GET['id']:1;
```

Which is bad because `$_GET['id']` is evaluated twice

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.3 you can simply do:

```
$a = $_GET['id'] ?: 1;
```

As from the PHP manual:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

If you don't have PHP 5.3 or greater you would have to use Sarfraz's (or better, delphist's) suggestion. However, in larger applications I tend to have the request variables wrapped in a way that I can specify a default value in the argument to the function retrieving the request. This has the advantage that it is cleaner (easier to understand) and it doesn't generate warnings if the index doesn't exist in the $_GET variable as I can use things like `isset` to check if the array index exists. I end up with something like:

Comment: I trust you. I just wanted to express that you've opened america for me  )

Comment: You could also do this: `$a = $_POST['id'] ?: $_GET['id'] ?: $_SESSION['id'] ?: 1 ;` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

its better to be

```
$a = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 1;
```

Comment: not quite. `if ( !empty( $_GET['id'] ) )` is the same as `if ( $_GET['id'] )` except that the former wont throw errors. What you've written is the same as `if ( !is_null( $_GET['id'] ) )` except that `isset` wont throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PHP doesn't support that syntax. The best you can do is to use ternary operator like your example:

```
$a = $_GET['id'] ? $_GET['id'] : 1;
```

The only option coming in mind for the equivalent stuff is that of using `Switch` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Array lookup in a single array is such a marginal amount of time that it really doesn't make a difference.

If you're cascading down a number of arrays, it would be faster to store the value in a temp variable:

```
$tempId = $example['this']['is']['an']['example']['where']['it\'s']['worth']['storing'];

$a = $tempId ? $tempId : 1;
```

Otherwise `$a = $_GET['id'] ? $_GET['id'] : 1;` is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.3 supports the following syntax:

```
$a = $_GET['id'] ?: 1;
```

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/ternary):

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.